# How to stop tmux from launching login shells?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tmux

TMUX defaults to launching shells as login shells. I am looking for a way to negate this behavior (so that it will launch non-login shells) in `.tmux.conf` file.

Currently I can use `tmux set-option -g default-command "/bin/bash"` from outside of tmux. But this can only be done when the tmux has already been launched and I can't seem to find a way to integrate it into the conf file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to modify your .tmux.conf like this:

> To disable this behaviour, add to ~/.tmux.conf:
>
> set -g default-command "${SHELL}"

From: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Start_a_non-login_shell

Comment: For bash (and possibly other shells), you may want to add the `-i` option to make the new shell an interactive one. That will cause it to source `~/.bashrc`, which can  be important for defining your shell prompt (`PS1` variable) and aliases.